# Additional space on UILabel in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView component that I use when I need it - the pickerView has a viewModel so I can inject an array of values and this is then displayed. There is nothing very complicated going on just a pickerView inside a view with some buttons in a header to cancel or confirm the choice.

[image]

You can now see my current issue. The UIPickerTableViewTitledCell contains a UILabel that for some reason doesn't align to the left - there is a small gap. This is very strange as it occurs when I set a fixed component width (as above) and also if I set the components to be the width of the screen.

[image]

I have tried:

- Looking at the content mode of the picker - changing this to `centre` doesn't seem to have any affect
- Playing around with the attributes and comparing them to other pickers that don't have this issue (in different components)
- Looking at the pickerDelegate methods - they all seem to be normal

  ```
   // MARK: - UIPickerViewDelegate

   func pickerView(_: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
       return viewModel?.numberOfRowsInPicker(forComponent: component) ?? 0
   }

   func pickerView(_: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
       return viewModel?.titleFor(row, forComponent: component)
   }

   func numberOfComponents(in _: UIPickerView) -> Int { viewModel?.numberOfComponentsInPicker ?? 1 }

   func pickerView(_: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
       if let width = viewModel?.width(forComponent: component) {
           return width
       }

       return UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat(viewModel?.numberOfComponentsInPicker ?? 1)
   }
  ```

None of these are doing anything special or different to what you would expect.

I have included an image of the xib file with the constraints on the pickerView:

[image]

My final solution might be to recreate the component step by step to see if the issue occurs after a certain time but ideally I want to understand why this is happening rather than just it disappearing.

Comment: Is the picker view inside a table view cell?

Comment: No just inside a UIView inside a UIViewController that is presented over the current screen

Comment: Can you show us how to make that happen? Obviously you know that this doesn't occur for every picker view in the world, so help us make it occur at all by letting us reproduce what you are doing.

Comment: It looks like you are **not** using constraints? If you are, please post that also - along with things to dulplicate the issue.

Comment: I have added an additional image of the PickerView inside the view and the constraints applied to it. As you can see I am only constraining the view itself - not doing anything to the labels inside (I don't know if I could affect the inside labels even if I wanted to)

Comment: Well, you still have to explain why your picker view doesn't look like mine. Maybe what is too wide for the screen is the superview (the main background view of that xib file). It looks pretty centered in your screenshot of the xib, so what is off-center would likely be the whole interface of the xib.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your picker view is too wide for the screen. By default, when you use `titleForRow`, the generated label has the same margin on *both* sides, as shown here:

[image]

The fact that we don't see the margin on the right of your picker view suggests that the right of your picker view is off the right side of the screen somewhere. Use autolayout constraints to position the picker view correctly regardless of the screen size.

Comment: When I constrain my pickerView inside the screen the same happens though - the picker fits within the screen by the label i still offset

Comment: And I demonstrated that it isn’t offset.